# Is Magneto officially an Omega Level Mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

I've read various forums suggesting he is an Omega Level Mutant (I agree with others that this term maybe needs rewording or defining) however in my experience he has never been officially mentioned as Omega Level. Some feats that he has managed should put him at Omega Level.

As far as I can see Magneto should be Omega Level as I think he is powerful enough to alter the environments on Earth by doing something with the Earth's Magnetic Field which in theory this could destroy the world.

If someone could give some extracts/info on the limit of the his powers. It would be great

Cheers

Comment: Definitely not an official Omega, considering that he filled out OM-457a incorrectly. He'll have to file an amended form, which will delay things by 12 to 18 weeks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

#### By officially, you mean mentioned by Marvel comics writers either in writing, or in passing dialog in a comic, to be an Omega-level mutant, then the answer is NO. No Marvel text has ever mentioned him as an Omega-level mutant.

This is just a sign of what a lack of documentation and standards will get you. An unclear definition of exactly an Omega level mutant is, and who qualifies. So in the interest of this document, I will define an Omega-level mutant by what has been shown in the Marvel Universe.

### **My Definition of an [Omega Level Mutant](http://ebonstorm.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/928/)** (unsanctioned by Marvel)

- The Omega-class metahuman is the Alpha-level mutant (any normal, trained mutant in the Marvel Universe) taken to an extreme. An Omega-level mutant is one with the most powerful genetic potential and expression of their mutant abilities.
- The term was first seen in the 1986 issue Uncanny X-Men #208, but was completely unexplained (beyond the obvious implication of it referring to an exceptional level of power). The term was not seen again until the 2001 limited series X-Men Forever.
- Some abilities depicted by mutants described as Omega-level include immortality, extreme manipulation of matter and energy, high levels of psionic ability, strong or extremely versatile telekinetic, or the potential to exist beyond the boundaries of the known physical universe.

**While no firm definition has been offered in comics, certain mutants have been confirmed/granted Omega-level status include:**

- [Apocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse_%28comics%29) (immortality, superhuman durability, molecular-level shape-changing)
- [Jean Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey) (telepathic/telekinetic; user of the Phoenix Force),
- [Vulcan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28Marvel_Comics%29) (vast superhuman energy manipulating capabilities),
- [Rachel Summers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Summers) (daughter of alternate timeline Jean Grey with similar powers),
- [Iceman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceman_%28comics%29) (cryo-hydro-kinetic),
- [Legion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_%28Marvel_Comics%29) (schizophrenic personalities with vast psionic powers),
- [Proteus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteus_%28Marvel_Comics%29) (reality-altering psychopathic vampire)
- [Franklin Richards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_Richards) (energy-manipulating, reality-altering powers).

The Omega has either a single power whose diverse usage and extreme power level allows them to perform a variety of feats at a level beyond any single Alpha’s ability; Magneto’s control over magnetism, Charles Xavier’s mental/telepathic prowess are two examples of this type of ability. (Though neither Charles Xavier nor Magneto's abilities have been confirmed as Omega-level. On the other hand, when their two powers were combined as [Onslaught](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onslaught_%28comics%29), they were easily the most powerful human entity on Earth to have ever existed.)

The other type of Omega has a wide range of powers that are normally found on entire super-teams and pushed to an obscene limit. Marvel’s Gladiator or the DCU’s Superman are an example of such a metahuman. Super-strength, superhuman levels of speed and reflex time, internal life support (proof against radiation, poison, no need to eat, sleep or excrete), invulnerability, energy projection powers, superior senses, and flight. What makes these two Omega-class is their virtually inexhaustible energy supplies. They are able to use their powers at full performance long after most Alpha-level mutants have become exhausted due to strain or fatigue.

### **EXAMPLES**

**[Elixir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elixir_%28comics%29):** His mutant power is biokinesis making him capable of controlling the biological structure of any organic matter including his own body. It is suspected his powers will eventually grow to the point of allowing him to manipulate genetic structures or even mutant genes and powers.

- He is capable of healing and repairing any form of biological injury **he can understand** (his power was limited by his knowledge of anatomy, physiology and genetics) He was able to regrow a heart in seconds, enabling the subject to survive the trauma.
- This was rectified when the Stepford Cockoos copied the Beast's knowledge of said subjects into Elixir's mind.
- He is also capable of creating disease, damaging tissues or altering genetic structures as well.

**[Nate Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nate_Grey)/[Jean Grey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey):** Both are vastly powerful psionicists (users of mental abilities) capable of both feats of telepathic prowess and matter manipulation at the atomic level.

- Nate's powers included telepathic prowess capable of reading and controlling multiple minds simultaneously, psychometry, telepathic projection, and astral projection over stellar distances.
- His ability to manipulate matter and energy included directing energy blast capable of destroying materials, altering the forces of gravity, create realistic holograms, manipulate atoms to phase through matter and create electromagnetic pulses.
- He could even alter his physical structure giving himself superhuman strength and durability.
- Jean Grey was not quite his physical equal but her telepathic powers were just as impressive. However, once she was coupled with the Phoenix force, she would be capable of doing feats similar to or equal to Nate's abilities.
- In some fashions, her energy manipulation abilities far exceeded Nate's. She, as the Phoenix was able to absorb the entire energy potential of a star, leaving it to nova as she absorbed all of its stores of energy which should have left it burning for millions of years.

**[Vulcan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28Marvel_Comics%29):** brother to Scott and Alex Summers

- Capable of psionically manipulating vast amounts of energy from diverse sources. He is able to manipulate any electromagnetic energy, as well as alternate dimensional energies such as the energy of Cyclops' optic blast or energy derived from dimensions of magic.
- He can generate powerful fields of electromagnetic force and track energy signatures over interstellar distances.
- He can mimic the powers of other mutants but only if they are nearby for him to replicate their energy signatures.
- He is also capable of generating energy constructs which can act as telekinetic proxies. While not possessing mental abilities, his powers make him resistant to them.

**I would argue, given the range of abilities of Magneto as shown over the decades, he should be considered an Omega-class mutant for the same reasons these four have. He has a formidable power over a fundamental force, in this case magnetism, allowing him a wide range of capabilities, both in terms of raw power as well as skill and precision with using this ability making him a match for nearly any and all of the previously listed Omega-level mutants.**

**[Magneto](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Magneto):** Is capable of manipulating magnetic forces both at the macroscopic and the microscopic levels. He is known as one of the most powerful mutants on the planet and has fought single-handedly against entire super-teams including the Avengers and the X-men.

- His control over magnetic forces gives him control of metals whether they be ferrous or nonferrous. Thor's hammer Mjolnir (made from Asgardian Uru) and Captain America's shield (made of Proto-Adamantium) or Wolverine's Beta Adamantium skeleton have been affected by Magneto's powers. Only specially-designed ceramics or plastics can resist direct manipulation via his powers.
- He has used his powers to manipulate and build complex machinery and can hold a large number of objects in precise patterns until he is ready to construct the device. Coupled with his genius-level intellect, he has created a wide array of technological achievements and devices.
- He can manipulate magnetic fields to generate powerful electromagnetic pulses and can even manipulate photons warping light around himself becoming invisible. He can manipulate the electromagnetic spectrum so that he may generate lightning bolts, emit vast amounts of infrared radiation or even manipulate the force of gravity.
- He is capable of generating electromagnetic barriers capable of resisting nuclear weapons and can exist in deep space using these fields to protect himself from radiation. He is able to propel himself at near-light speeds. He has also been able to generate wormholes to travel through space, teleporting himself and others safely.
- He is able to channel his powers inward, increasing his strength, durability and reflexes. He can manipulate chemical bonds allowing him to rearrange matter (though doing this puts great strain on his powers).
- He is innately resistant to all but the most powerful telepathic assaults and when he utilizes his powers, he is completely immune to telepathy, suggestion or domination-based telepathic attacks.

Comment: I realize this question is a couple years old, but IIRC Magneto was one of The Twelve selected by Apocalypse, all of whom were (potential) Omega-level mutants that represented aspects of reality.

Comment: As of September 2019 this answer is outdated. See [the most recent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/220733/76048), and [my comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24876/is-magneto-officially-an-omega-level-mutant/220733#comment602730_24882) on spong's answer.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is a very old post, but since it is the top result in the Google search I think it's important to notice that now, with the *House of X* reboot, Magneto is officially an Omega level mutant. Marvel also defined more clearly what exactly is an Omega level mutant in *House of X* issue # 1 (2019):

> **OMEGA LEVEL MUTANT:** A mutant whose dominant power is deemed to register -- or reach -- an undefinable upper limit of that power's specific classification.
>
> **FOR EXAMPLE**: Both Magneto and Forge are the most powerful mutants of their power types on the planet Earth [Magnetism and Technopathy, respectively], but what makes Magneto, and not Forge, an Omega level mutant is that the upper limit of Forge's measurable powers could hypothetically be surpassed [and, in fact, has by multiple humans on the planet], while the upper limit of Magneto's power cannot be surpassed in any measurable fashion.
>
> **Note**: *Omega level is a classification of a single mutant power. While it is quite common that mutants manifest multiple powers, only one is normally of Omega level.*
>
> **FOR EXAMPLE**: *While Jean Grey is both a telepath and a telekinetic, she is only an Omega level telepath.*

[image: screenshot of above definition]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE, and thank you for the update! I'm surprised that none of the existing answers have been updated to address this already. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 8):

No, he isn't *officially* an Omega level mutant, although he *potentially* is.

The problem is that there isn't a formal definition for what an Omega level is. From the wikipedia section on [Marvel's Omega level mutatants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_%28Marvel_Comics%29#Omega-level_mutants):

> No firm definition has been offered in comics. Examples of mutants
>   that have been confirmed as Omega-level include Jean Grey, Vulcan,
>   Rachel Summers, Iceman, Legion, Elixir, and Franklin Richards.

Comment: I'll try to update this answer later, as I'm currently away from my desk at a conference.

Comment: Poor fellow, wand'ring that conference hall for more than half a decade....

Comment: The section you link to has now been updated with an official definition of an Omega-level mutant, which includes Magneto. You may wish to update your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess neither Magneto or Professor X allowed anyone to find out the limits of their powers. Both were very smart and let anyone to capture them in order to check their true limits.

If you take reference from the films, Charles told Eric that if Eric accessed the good inside himself, he would possess a power that no one could match, not even Charles. Now in X-Men Last Stand he was already old and obviously without access to that good that Charles mentioned, so he was not at Jean's level, but maybe younger and without his blinding hate for humans, he could be even more powerful than Jean.

Comment: So far in the movies, the term "Omega Level Mutant" doesn't even exist.